# Convert an old PC to Ubuntu File Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware-raid, file-server

I have an old PC (P-III 550Mhz, 512MB RAM) which has reliably served as my local development server for years.

I now want give it this box additional role of a file server for network backups, by using RAID 1 with two 2TB SATA Hard Drives for redundancy.

Since this old PC only supports IDE drives, is it possible to just buy a PCI SATA card to get a 2TB SATA RAID setup? and if so can anyone recommend a card that is known for working well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd go with a non-raid (JBOD-mode) SATA controller and use software raid. [These cards](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124020) are well-supported in the Linux kernel. Unless you have *very* stringent performance needs (which is not likely due to your use of a PIII as a file server), software RAID will serve you just fine, and is much easier to manage, monitor, and recover if need be.

Comment: Downvote - interesting. Care to explain yourself? I have a fair amount of sound reasoning to back up my answer, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: i brought you back up; i think your answer was just fine.

Comment: Thanks eric, though I wasn't fishing for upvotes. I was just honestly curious to hear what criticisms people might have with my answer.